# JavaCV with java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: javacv

The code is very simple, just open a picture.
But when I run this I have an error like this:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread_1(Ljava/lang/String;)J
    at org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread_1(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread(Imgcodecs.java:112)
```

According to the searched solution, I add this `System.load(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME)` to the `main()`, doesn't work:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Expecting an absolute path of the library: opencv_java401
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:806)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
```

Or this `System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME)`, still not work:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java401 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
```

My project is build by gradle, the dependencies is (official doc):

```
compile group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv-platform', version: '1.5'
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You forgot to call `Loader.load(opencv_java.class)` as mentioned in the README.md file here: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/opencv#documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self answer.
My `import` is wrong. It should be
`import static org.bytedeco.opencv.global.opencv_imgcodecs.imread`
instead of
`import static org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread`
This error caused the wrong package to be used.

The correct code is:

```java
import org.bytedeco.opencv.opencv_core.Mat;
import static org.bytedeco.opencv.global.opencv_imgcodecs.imread;

public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mat image = imread("/root/test.png");
        System.out.println("width：" + image.cols());
        System.out.println("height：" + image.rows());
    }
}
```